# Vine-like, deep-rooted very aggressive weed - what is it and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: weed-control, identification

I've been trying to find out what weed this is (see photo), but I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

The weed mainly grows in the hedges of the garden, and appears to be choking it. It twists up the stems of the hedges like a vine. One hedge has already died completely because of this weed.

I've been cutting it off at the stem, but the weed is very deeply rooted and is very hard to get rid off. Does anyone know of any (ecological) ways of removing this weed permanently?

[image: leaves]

[image]

Comment: does the vine produces any flowers or fruit? If yes to either, do you have a photo to share? Where in the world are you located?

Comment: The flowers it produces are the white bell-like flowers you see on the photo. I am located in Belgium, Europe.

Comment: Doh! I'm a muppet for not noticing them initially :) ["Mancuniensis" answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/vine-like-deep-rooted-very-aggressive-weed-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of/1687#1687) appears to be a good one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks very much like a **[Hop plant](http://www.aphotoflora.com/d_humulus_lupulus_hop.html)**  (*Humulus*), a vigorous twining climber with  coarsely serrated (toothed) leaves that have three to five lobes.

Hops are difficult to eradicate, even with a weedkiller; a neighbor of mine has several on his vegetable plot and has unsuccessfully been trying to remove them, without resorting to chemicals, for several years.

Unless you're willing to take the chemical route - you could spray their leaves with Roundup before they flower - the only options are probably hand-pulling and continually cutting the stems down to ground level to weaken their root system, or turning the hops to good account by using them for home-brewing ;)

Comment: Little late here but if it is hops clipping them as they sprout is just making the root system stronger.

Answer (score 5):

Not even knowing what the weed is I would recommend one course of action. What I would do is first find the weed where it comes out of the ground. Then cut it off about a foot or so above the ground. If there any leaves left spray or paint them with Round Up or other applicable herbicide. If there are no leaves just wait for some leaves to appear and then treat them. I would remove all the dead vines from the plant to help prevent seeds from falling. After you have done all that keep an eye out for any new seedlings getting started. Those should easily pull out by hand. That should take care of it. Good luck.